# Need help on HC05 and Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, hc-05

I am new to Arduino programming and currently working on this instructable
http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-Led-RGB/ (following this diagram http://cdn.instructables.com/F6Q/IMHF/I0LCDK6B/F6QIMHFI0LCDK6B.LARGE.jpg)

I have ordered these parts as well.

1. Arduino Nano: www.ebay.in/itm/Arduino-Nano-SOLDERED-PINS-V3-0-ATmega328-CH340G-BUY-2-GET-1-USB-CABLE-FREE-/172117729247?
2. HC-05: www.amazon.in/Bluetooth-Transceiver-Module-TTL-Outputs-HC05/dp/B00R95Y0AK?ie=UTF8&psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=ox_sc_act_title_2&smid=A1NDZY44BCNIQJ

My questions are:

1. Is there need to add voltage divider? If yes can you please provide link?
2. Can I connect two 5050 RGB modules?
3. Will 12 V, 1 A will be enough to power this board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1A will be enough to power you arduino but the total powerconsumtion will depend on the amount of leds that you want to drive. If you follow the instuctable, it should be enoug but it's never a good idea to use your power source at max capacity all the time.

It allows you to connect 2 modules indeed.

Why would you need a voltage divider?

Comment: hc05  logic works on 3.3v please check the ebay link  thats why l want know about divider

Comment: Your arduino can give you 3.3V for powering it. If your board doesn't accept 5V logic, then you'll need a voltage level shifter.

Comment: do you have any link or example which I can use?

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009